# How to exclude a specific link from Symfony route pattern regexp?

Tags: regex, symfony

I have this parameters in my `app/config/security.yml`

```
parameters:
    sylius.security.api_regex: "^/api"
```

This matches all the links like `/api/v1/a/`, `/api/custom/b/` etc...

I want specific route let's say: `/api/custom/some/info/` to be removed from the match.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything that works at least partially?

Comment: I tried `^/api(?!/api/custom/some/info/)` Also the thing is I can not change the route, an external service depend on that.

Comment: Also the regex101.com doesn't really help, the behavior in Symfony is a bit different, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `^/api(?!/api/custom/some/info/)` regex matches the `/api` at the start of the string, and then fails the match if it is followed with `/api/custom/some/info/`.

You may fix it with

```
^/api(?!/custom/some/info/)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mYayBm/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `/api` - a literal substring...
- `(?!/custom/some/info/)` - not immediately followed with `/custom/some/info/`.

Now, if the last slash is optional, you may use alternate it with the end of string:

```
^/api(?!/custom/some/info(?:/|$))
                         ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you for good answer, I tried it but it doesn't work. What I want to do is to disable the oAuth for this specific route. (everything in `/api` is under oAuth). At least now I know the problem is not in the regexp. Now the problem can be somewhere else (probably some config interfere).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a firewall enabled in symfony, simply set the access control, make this path at the top of the list and allow a role on it that no-one but you have.

<kbd>**app/config/security.yml**</kbd>

```
access_control:
    #If route is matched matched, will block access to anyone not having ROLE_PRIVATE
    - { path: ^/api/custom/some/info/, roles: [ROLE_PRIVATE] }
    #Else if route is not matched, will allow access to everyone
    - { path: ^/api, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY] }
```

Comment: That worked, thank you very much, but I'll accept @Wiktor answer as It's the corrent answer to my question.